# Install Manage Package manually and then link it to the AppExchange one

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, package-install

I want to install a Managed package on a production org.

The first installation would be done manually, but later on, the same package will be available on the Salesforce AppExchange.

My questions are the following:

1. Will the package installed manually be automatically linked to the AppExchange one? I'm wondering if, for example, by pushing an upgrade to the package in the AppExchange, this will be received by the production org.
2. If not 1., do I have to uninstall the package from the production org and re-install it from the AppExchange?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The identity of a managed package does not change after it is submitted to Security Review or posted on the AppExchange.

In this scenario, provided that

1. The version installed is not a beta (betas are not upgradeable).
2. You do not change to a different package or namespace.
3. If this is a 2GP, the line of ancestry is unbroken.

you will be able to upgrade your org from a pre-AppExchange package version to a post-AppExchange package version.